# Stop a Function, jQuery

Tags: jquery, die

I'm using this blink function

```
(function($)
{
  $.fn.blink = function(options)
   {
       var defaults = { delay:500 };
       var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

       return this.each(function()
       {
           var obj = $(this);
           setInterval(
            function(){
               if($(obj).css("visibility") == "visible") {
                  $(obj).css('visibility','hidden');
               }
               else{
                  $(obj).css('visibility','visible');
               }
             },
            options.delay);
        });
    }
}(jQuery))

$("#bootUp p").blink({delay:300});
```

I'd like for it to stop on window.load

I'm not sure how to do it, exactly? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FN2Jm/3/)**

You need to track the ints returned from setInterval and then clearInterval for each of them.

```
var intervals = new Array();

(function($)
{
  $.fn.blink = function(options)
   {
       var defaults = { delay:500 };
       var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

       return this.each(function()
       {
           var obj = $(this);
           intervals[intervals.length] = setInterval(
            function(){
               if($(obj).css("visibility") == "visible") {
                  $(obj).css('visibility','hidden');
               }
               else{
                  $(obj).css('visibility','visible');
               }
             },
            options.delay);
        });
    }
}(jQuery))

$("#bootUp p").blink({delay:300});
$("#bootUp2 p").blink({delay:300});

$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i=0;i<intervals.length;i++){
        clearInterval(intervals[i]);
    } 
});
```

Comment: @duttka, I ran that through jshint and it failed?

Comment: Updated with a live example on jsfiddle. Some (not all) of the errors from jshint were in the original code you posted :p

Comment: this won't work if you call `blink` more than once though, right?

Comment: @Emmett if you were going to do that, then keep var i outside the blink function so that it appends further intervals instead of overwriting at index 0. Or just use intervals.length instead of i

Comment: @druttka A better approach might be to have `blink` return an array of ids, instead of relying on a global var.

Comment: @Emmett I don't disagree, but for the sake of time and clarity, I tried to make the smallest modification possible to meet the OPs goal while demonstrating the fundamental concept required (use clearInterval). Think about both of your questions at the same time: if you have blink return an array of ids, but then call it twice, you're still going to have to keep up with the total list somewhere?

Comment: I've updated my answer and the jsfiddle demo to demonstrate calling blink and then stopping it on multiple divs.

Comment: @druttka Yea I see why you wrote it the way you did -- I just wanted to make those observations, in case anyone comes across this in the future and pastes your code in into their project.

Answer (score 0):

The most correct solution would be store the ids returned by `setInterval`, and then clear them all with `clearInterval`. However, a more simple/braindead approach is just:

```
$("#bootUp p").replaceWith($("#bootUp p").clone());
```